# How to create an empty file in Deno?

Tags: deno

As per [deno documentation for writeFile](https://deno.land/typedoc/index.html#writefile) if I want to write in a file and overwrite if the file already exists I need this command -

```
await Deno.writeFile("hello1.txt", data);  // overwrite "hello1.txt" or create it
```

What I need is to create an empty file and if a file with the same name already exists overwrite it with an empty file, so I tried to run the function without data and I am getting this error.

```
await Deno.writeFile("hello1.txt");
 An argument for 'data' was not provided.
        data: Uint8Array,
```

How can I create an empty file in Deno and overwrite any file exists with the same name?

Answer (score 3):

Pass an empty `Uint8Array` to `Deno.writeFile`

```
await Deno.writeFile("./hello1.txt", new Uint8Array());
```

You can also use `Deno.open` with `truncate: true`

```
await Deno.open("./hello1.txt", { create: true, write: true, truncate: true });
```

or [`Deno.create`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.create):

```js
await Deno.create("./hello1.txt")
```

---

Alternatively, if you know the file already exists you can use [`Deno.truncate`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.truncate)

```
await Deno.truncate("./hello1.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option works perfectly fine, but Deno.truncate does not create an empty file, it empty an existing file. It is giving an error if the file is not already present

Comment: Thought you always had the file, I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Deno.create`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.create):

> Creates a file if none exists or truncates an existing file and resolves to an instance of `Deno.File`.

```
await Deno.create("hello1.txt")
```

Process deeper file paths with possibly not existent directories safely:

```js
import { ensureFile } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_file.ts";
const file = "./deep/hello1.txt"; // `deep` doesn't need to exist
await ensureFile(file); // ensures file and containing directories
await Deno.truncate(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writeTextFile` and pass an empty `string`. Rest as suggested above, use `ensureFile and truncate` for other needs.

```
(async function() {
  await Deno.writeTextFile("./helloworld.txt", "")
})()
```